# Python Social Auth Redirect to Wrong URL

Tags: python, django, redirect, python-social-auth

I use python-social-auth for my django site, let's say: `example.io`. It was working. But, after redeploy, and try to log in via Twitter, it redirect to wrong URL, `example` only, without the `.io`

I also tried to use another url, `staging.example.io`, it still redirects to `example`, without `staging` and `io`

I try to deploy it in local, so the URL is `localhost:12345`, and it's redirecting to the right url (to localhost:12345 or 127.0.0.1:12345), and sign in successfully.

Anyone knows something about it?

Update:
I have tried to use another url, for example, abc.def.com but stil redirect to `example` (withouth .io). It also happened for LinkedIn social auth.

Comment: Any change to your HTTP server (nginx/apache), or WSGI server (unicorn)? To me it sounds like the HOST is not being set properly and the redirect URLs are being generated with the wrong domain.

Comment: @omab I have set the server_name to example.io and staging.example.io, but it's still doesn't work properly. I even create new Twitter app, but it still doesn't work